# PSTricks: charpath on a curve (like textpath)

Tags: pstricks

I am interested in drawing a specially rendered text on a curve.

The LaTeX package [pst-text](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-text) provides a function to draw text on a curve (`pstextpath`) and a function to specially render text (`pscharpath`):

**MWE for what I want to combine:**

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage{pst-plot}
    \usepackage{pst-text}
    \usepackage[final]{pst-pdf}

    \begin{document}
      \psset{unit=.5cm,plotpoints=200}
      \begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(5,1)
        % Specially Rendered Text:
        \rput(0,-1)
        {    
          \DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{10pt}                                               
          \pscharpath[linecolor=orange,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black,linewidth=0.3pt]{\RM Specially Rendered Text}
        }

        % Text on a Curve:
        \pstextpath[c](0,0)
        {
          \pscustom[linestyle=none]
          {
            \psplot{-3}{3}{0.5 x x mul 0.1 mul sub}
          }
        }
        {
          \DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{s}{n}{10pt}
          \RM Text on a Curve
        }                       
      \end{pspicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Summary: How to write specially rendered text on a curve?

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: @Herbert I guess the problem is replication of the glowing effect below to the curved path.

Comment: ah I see. That is possibble but needs some modifications of the code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is really an answer, but according to the documentation on `\pscharpath` and `\pstextpath`:

> With the optional `*`, the character path is not removed from the
>   PostScript environment at the end. This is mainly for special hacks.
>   For example, you can use `\pscharpath*` in the first argument of
>   `\pstextpath`, and thus typeset text along the character path of some
>   other text. However, you cannot combine `\pscharpath` and `\pstextpath` in
>   any other way. E.g., you cannot typeset character outlines along a
>   path, and then fill and stroke the outlines with `\pscharpath`.

Comment: It says : You cannont typeset character outlines along a path, and then fill and stroke the outlines with \pscharpath...

It'll require a more complex transformation. Sorry, dude

Comment: @Pierre Yeah, I don't know the mechanics behind `\pscharpath` and `\pstextpath`, but I have the feeling it should be possible to merge them (even if it requires a deeper hack).

Comment: @Pierre I'm not sure I understand your comment which seems only to repeat the same information from the quote in my answer.